# Можно ли использовать SwiftUI с iOS 11.x и выше?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Есть приложение с использованием SwiftUI. Будет ли оно работать на старых версиях iOS? Начиная с iOS 11 и выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Минимальная версия для SwiftUI проектов iOS 13.